# Why do I get a KeyError in this generator?

Tags: python, dictionary, generator

I've got the following dictionary:

```py
d = {
    'A': {
        'param': {
            '1': {
                'req': True,
            },
            '2': {
                'req': True,
            },
        },
    },
    'B': {
        'param': {
            '3': {
                'req': True,
            },
            '4': {
                'req': False,
            },
        },
    },
}
```

I want to have a generator which will give me for each first level keys, the required parameters.

```py
req = {}
for key in d:
    req[key] = (p for p in d[key]['param'] if d[key]['param'][p].get('req', False))
```

So here, for each key in `d`, I get parameter `p` only if `req` is `True`.

However, when I try to use my generator, it raises a `KeyError` exception:

```py
>>> req
{'A': <generator object <genexpr> at 0x27b8960>,
 'B': <generator object <genexpr> at 0x27b8910>}
>>> for elem in req['A']:
...     print elem
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-a96226f95cce> in <module>()
----> 1 for elem in req['A']:
      2     print elem
      3 

<ipython-input-4-1732088ccbdb> in <genexpr>((p,))
      1 for key in d:
----> 2         req[key] = (p for p in d[key]['param'] if d[key]['param'][p].get('req', False))
      3 

KeyError: '1'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generator expressions you assign to `req[key]` binds on the `key` variable. But `key` changes from 'A' to 'B' in the loop. When you iterate over the first generator expression, it will evaluate `key` to 'B' in its `if` condition, even though `key` was 'A' when you created it.

The conventional way to bind to a variable's value and not its reference, is to wrap the expression in a lambda with a default value, and then call it immediately.

```
for key in d:
    req[key] = (lambda key=key: (p for p in d[key]['param'] if d[key]['param'][p].get('req', False)))()
```

Result:

```
1
2
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because upon execution of the generator, the *latest* value of `key` is used.

Suppose the `for key in d:` iterates over the keys in the order `'A', 'B'`, the 1st generator is supposed to work with `key = 'A'`, but due to closure issues, it uses the item with `'B'` as key. And this has no `'1'` sub-entry.

Even worse, the `key` variable in the generator has two different values: the `for p in d[key]['param']` part uses the "correct" value, while the `if d[key]['param'][p].get('req', False)` uses the "closure value", which is the last one.